# Can workbox help me unpack paginated data in to a cache?

Tags: workbox

Let's say I have a RESTful architecture for blog posts:

- `/api/blogs?from=0&to=30` will return me 30 posts.

  - `/api/blogs/page/1` would return me the same 30 posts.
- `/api/post/13` will return the content of blog post #13.

Assuming that the shape of a post object is more or less the same between those two REST endpoints, you could reasonably get away with making the assumption that the content from `/api/post/13` would be included in the content from `/api/blogs/page/1`.

In this use case, I'm attempting to parse those paginated responses and use them to warm the cache for individual posts.

If I were writing the caching myself, I'd only create one cache for `blogs`, and each time I requested a page of them, I'd iterate through the response and add something to the cache as appropriate:

```
function oncePaginatedResultsFetched(jsonResults) {
    caches.open('blogs-cache').then(cache => {
        jsonResults.forEach(result => cache.put(`/api/blog/${result.id}`, result))
    });
}
```

This populates the cache well enough.

What I'm finding is that when I attempt a similar thing when I'm also using Workbox, the various out-of-the-box strategies do not find these items I've pushed in to the cache.

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    //api\/post\/(\d+)/,
    workbox.strategies.cacheFirst({
        cacheName: "posts"
    }),
    "GET"
);

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    //api\/blogs/,
    workbox.strategies.staleWhileRevalidate({
        cacheName: "blog-page-list",
        plugins: [{
            // Take the collection of items returned in the list response, then individually
            // cache each item in the collection.
            // This is ... almost certainly a hack around workbox.
            // todo: set appropriate cache + date headers in the request and response objects.
            cachedResponseWillBeUsed: babelHelpers.asyncToGenerator(
                function* ({ cacheName, request, matchOptions, cachedResponse }) {
                    const newResponse = cachedResponse.clone();
                    const data = yield cachedResponse.json();
                    if (data) {
                        const cache = yield caches.open("posts");
                        for (let i = 0, ii = data.length; i < ii; i++) {
                            let item = data[i];
                            let body = JSON.stringify(item);
                            let res = new Response(body, {
                                headers: new Headers({
                                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                                    'Content-Length': body.length,
                                    'Date': new Date().toUTCString(),
                                })
                            });
                            yield cache.put(`/api/post/${item.id}`, res);
                        }
                    }

                    return newResponse;
                }
            ),
        }]
    }),
    "GET"
);
```

When I run this, chrome's devtools tells me the `cache.match` call internal to workbox's strategy for the `/api/blogs` route returns `undefined`.

I think I'm missing something important, probably about how `cache.match` is being used by Workbox, or how the request/response objects are used in the cache API, or about assumptions I'm making on how cache hits work, or all of the above. I'm just not sure what it is yet. Anybody have thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a problem with CORS. Since I was making a request to a remote instance, I needed to create a request with the fully-qualified URL instead of a root-relative one. Once I did that, this worked as expected.